# PHP - Sort Array by multiple Values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, array-multisort

i've got a little problem. I want to create a table with sccores for an League and got every Team in an array that looks like this:

```
Array ( 
[35006454-f94e-4d2e-90a4-3e09cbae7885] => Array ( 
    [teamid] => 35006454-f94e-4d2e-90a4-3e09cbae7885 
    [teamtitle] => Team0 
    [avatar] => Link.jpg 
    [points] => 8 
    [wins] => 4 
    [loss] => 0 
    [draws] => 0 
    [matches] => 4 
    ) 
[807bafad-fb44-4062-bc87-d6c7566c943d] => Array ( 
    [teamid] => 807bafad-fb44-4062-bc87-d6c7566c943d 
    [teamtitle] => Team1
    [avatar] => Link.jpg 
    [points] => 6 
    [wins] => 3 
    [loss] => 1 
    [draws] => 0 
    [matches] => 4 
    )
)
```

Now i want to sort that array first after Points, then after Wins, Draws and Loss.. At this moment i only figured out how to sort after Points. I tried reading tutorials about multisort but my mind cant bring it to use in this case. Can someone show me how to do it?

Comment: @nice_dev OP already considered multisort if you read the last paragraph, please retract flag

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found the answer in the other question - My Solution:

`array_multisort( array_column( $teamstable, 'points' ), SORT_DESC, array_column($teamstable, 'matches' ), SORT_DESC, $teamstable );`

Comment: @DownloadPizza Not needed. OP got the help from there.